# Feed dialog direct URL not working in IE

Tags: php, facebook, internet-explorer, header

This PHP header function is working in all browsers except IE. It is loading the Facebook feed dialog into a canvas page within Facebook (iframe).

In IE:

The header is loading in Facebook, but not the actual feed dialog, just a blue box stating 'an error has occurred' without specific details of that error.

All other browsers the header works as expected, and loads the page within the canvas frame.

The script inserts the results of a form into the MySQL database, and if this is successful, the header then redirects the user to the feed dialog.

Therefor I am concerned that the problem is either with IE processing the variable `$feeddialogurl`, or whether there are some security restrictions with IE that are preventing it from loading.

*Update - after more testing the header is working as expected, the URL works when pasted directly into IE.

Do you have any more suggestions please?

```
$feeddialogurl = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
app_id=254705324634259&".$applink."&
picture=".$apppicture."&
name=".$appname."&
caption=".$appcaption."&
description=".$appdescription."&
redirect_uri=".$redirecturi;

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
else
{
header("Location: $feeddialogurl");
exit;
}
mysql_close($con);
ob_end_flush();
```

Please see the error message in IE below. The feed dialog is loaded into the app frame (hence duplication of the Facebook top menu bar) This works in all other browsers bar IE.

[image: Error in IE]

Comment: What web server and PHP [SAPI](http://www.php.net/php_sapi_name) are you using?

Comment: have you tried copying out the generated url and loading it into IE manually?

Comment: who told you that IE requires `die` rather than `exit`? The two are exactly the same in PHP: it says as much in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php

Comment: @MarcB I've just tried loading the generated URL in manually and it works fine in IE. Just once it's loaded in the header, instead of the dialog box appearing correctly, the box displays "An error occurred. Please try later".

Comment: @MichaelHampton PHP SAPI = apache2handler   ["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]=>
  string(31) "Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) PHP/5.3.10"

Comment: @Spudley This article makes reference to use 'die();' where I would otherwise use exit. The article is here: [link](http://figured-it-out.com/figured-out.php?sid=181) but upon reading it again can see my error.

Comment: Did you maybe forget to URL-encode all the parameters you’re putting into the URL correctly …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by using the Fb.UI Javascript method.

Read more here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/